# record virtual memory use in netlogo over time

Tags: netlogo

I am running netlogo on a HPC cluster, and I wondered if there is any way to output-print the java heap used **over time**?

I am trying to optimize the heap space used for a large model with loads of GIS data, but the HPC cluster only gives limited information on how much is used at which step.

Comment: You probably need a Java/JVM expert here rather than a NetLogo expert; the question is not NetLogo-specific.

Comment: The reason I thought it might be possible, is because if you run it on a regular computer, you can go to help>about netlogo>system for checking the heap space used. Maybe there was a netlogo command that outputted this info. I will check with a java expert, thanks for your answer.

Comment: The code in NetLogo that produces that readout in the “About NetLogo” dialog is here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/533131ddb63da21ac35639e61d67601a3dae7aa2/src/main/org/nlogo/util/SysInfo.scala#L28-L39 . You can see that it's just called some routines in the Java standard library (in `java.lang.Runtime`). You could write a little NetLogo extension that called the same routines.

Comment: Okee great thank you! I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe tools exist for monitoring JVM heap usage; I don't know much about that, but it isn't actually a NetLogo-specific topic, so you might look into that separately.

If you want to gather the information from within NetLogo itself:

As you point out in a comment, the "About NetLogo" dialog displays heap usage numbers. The code that retrieves those numbers is here: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/533131ddb63da21ac35639e61d67601a3dae7aa2/src/main/org/nlogo/util/SysInfo.scala#L28-L39

You can see that it's just calling some routines in the Java standard library (in java.lang.Runtime). You could write a little NetLogo extension that calls the same routines.

Comment: Did anyone write a netlogo extension to monitor the RAM usage in 7 years ? :)